# Flutter, reading multiple values from function

Tags: list, function, flutter

This is a followup of a question I had a couple off days ago about my first flutter app.
Following advice from PRO I changed my code so that it did what I wanted.
The only problem is that from the function I get only 1 value.
Pro advised to make a list, which worked in the function like it should.
Only how to get these values in a textfield is not clear to me.
I can only show what I want bij sending the full code.
Later I want to build on the same principal with more outcome values.
I use value.toString() as well as value[1].toString().
The first gives me the first value, the second only a caracter.
I hope someone can help

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Buis());
}

class Buis extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  BuisState createState() => BuisState();
}

class BuisState extends State<Buis> {
  var kap2 = '';
  var buizen2 = '';
  var diam2 = '';
  var spev = '';
  var spo = '';
  var value;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    TextEditingController kapController = TextEditingController(text: '9.60');
    TextEditingController buizenController = TextEditingController(text: '12');
    TextEditingController diamController = TextEditingController(text: '51');

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(
            child: Text("Specifiek buis vermogen"),
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 20),

                  // Input kap breedte
                  Container(
                    width: 170,
                    height: 30,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: kapController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 8),
                        labelText: "Kap breedte (mtr)",
                        hintText: "$kap2",
                        fillColor: Colors.cyan[200],
                        filled: true,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),

                  // Input aantal buizen
                  Container(
                    width: 170,
                    height: 30,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: buizenController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 8),
                        labelText: "Aantal buizen",
                        hintText: "$buizen2",
                        fillColor: Colors.cyan[200],
                        filled: true,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),

                  // Input buis diameter
                  Container(
                    width: 170,
                    height: 30,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: diamController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 8),
                        labelText: "Buis diameter (mm)",
                        hintText: '$diam2',
                        fillColor: Colors.cyan[200],
                        filled: true,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),

                  //  Uitkomsten
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[

                      SizedBox(height: 20),

                      // Berekenen knop
                      Center(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                          onPressed: () {
                            value = getValue(kapController.text, buizenController.text, diamController.text).toString();
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          child: Text("Berekenen".toUpperCase(),
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),

                      Text(
                        'Specifiek vermogen     ',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),

                      // Specifiek vermogen
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
                        width: 80,
                        height: 30,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red[200],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(
                            left: Radius.circular(40),
                            right: Radius.circular(40),
                          ),
                          border: Border.all(width: 1.0),
                        ),

                        child:Text(
                          value[2].toString(), //here I read the first outcome
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),

                      Text(
                        'Specifiek oppervlak       ',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),

                      // Specifiek oppervlak
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
                        width: 80,
                        height: 30,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red[200],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(
                            left: Radius.circular(40),
                            right: Radius.circular(40),
                          ),
                          border: Border.all(width: 1.0),
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          value[3].toString(), // and here the second
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),

                      SizedBox(height: 60),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

getValue(kap, buizen, diam) {
  var kap1 = double.parse(kap);
  var buizen1 = double.parse(buizen);
  var diam1 = double.parse(diam);

  var spev = 1.7 * (diam1 / 51) * (buizen1 / kap1);
  spev = num.parse(spev.toStringAsFixed(2));
  var spo = (buizen1 * diam1 * 0.1) / kap1;
  spo = num.parse(spo.toStringAsFixed(2));
  print("Spev is " '$spev');
  print("Spo is " '$spo');

  List<double> valueList = List<double>();
  valueList.add(spev);
  valueList.add(spo);

  print(valueList);
  return valueList;

}
```

Comment: your query is not clear to me :(

Comment: I understand. But PRO asked me to make a new question so he could check the code

Comment: are you trying to get values from a function? IF yes then you could make a list and store the values to the list as:

``List<String> list;``
``list.add(functionName());`` // add a string value from the function
``list.add(functionName());`` // add another string value from the function
.... //so on

//to access the values, call ``list[index]``. for example if you want to set the input field text, do like this ``hintText: "${list[0]}"`` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Pim, there are few errors in your code,

- you are explicitly calling list item on widget build, here you don't have the value yet
- you are converting list into string with `value = getValue(kapController.text, buizenController.text, diamController.text).toString();` , not sure why you're doing this but this in not correct.

Try assigning empty value to your textFields on widget build and then assign actual value on button press and finally refresh the state like so,

```
class Buis extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  BuisState createState() => BuisState();
}

class BuisState extends State<Buis> {
  var kap2 = '';
  var buizen2 = '';
  var diam2 = '';
  var spev = '';
  var spo = '';
  var value;
  var firstValue = '';
  var secondValue = '';
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    TextEditingController kapController = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController buizenController = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController diamController = TextEditingController();

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(
            child: Text("Specifiek buis vermogen"),
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 20),

                  // Input kap breedte
                  Container(
                    width: 170,
                    height: 30,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: kapController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 8),
                        labelText: "Kap breedte (mtr)",
                        hintText: "$kap2",
                        fillColor: Colors.cyan[200],
                        filled: true,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),

                  // Input aantal buizen
                  Container(
                    width: 170,
                    height: 30,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: buizenController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 8),
                        labelText: "Aantal buizen",
                        hintText: "$buizen2",
                        fillColor: Colors.cyan[200],
                        filled: true,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),

                  // Input buis diameter
                  Container(
                    width: 170,
                    height: 30,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: diamController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 8),
                        labelText: "Buis diameter (mm)",
                        hintText: '$diam2',
                        fillColor: Colors.cyan[200],
                        filled: true,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),

                  //  Uitkomsten
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[

                      SizedBox(height: 20),

                      // Berekenen knop
                      Center(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                          onPressed: () {
                            value = getValue(kapController.text, buizenController.text, diamController.text);
                            //Depending on how many value you will have;
                            firstValue = value[0].toString();
                            secondValue = value[1].toString();
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          child: Text("Berekenen".toUpperCase(),
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),

                      Text(
                        'Specifiek vermogen     ',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),

                      // Specifiek vermogen
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
                        width: 80,
                        height: 30,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red[200],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(
                            left: Radius.circular(40),
                            right: Radius.circular(40),
                          ),
                          border: Border.all(width: 1.0),
                        ),

                        child:Text(
                          firstValue.toString(), //here I read the first outcome
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),

                      Text(
                        'Specifiek oppervlak       ',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),

                      // Specifiek oppervlak
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
                        width: 80,
                        height: 30,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red[200],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(
                            left: Radius.circular(40),
                            right: Radius.circular(40),
                          ),
                          border: Border.all(width: 1.0),
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          secondValue.toString(), // and here the second
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),

                      SizedBox(height: 60),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

getValue(kap, buizen, diam) {
  var kap1 = double.parse(kap);
  var buizen1 = double.parse(buizen);
  var diam1 = double.parse(diam);

  var spev = 1.7 * (diam1 / 51) * (buizen1 / kap1);
  spev = num.parse(spev.toStringAsFixed(2));
  var spo = (buizen1 * diam1 * 0.1) / kap1;
  spo = num.parse(spo.toStringAsFixed(2));
  print("Spev is " '$spev');
  print("Spo is " '$spo');

  List<double> valueList = List<double>();
  valueList.add(spev);
  valueList.add(spo);

  print(valueList);
  return valueList;

}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: I try'd your example, but if you change ie 9.60 to 12 or whatever, it jumps back to 9.60. It does the correct calculation tho.  ...I build my program from examples on the net, It is not that I understand what I am doing completely, therefor mistakes happen easily.

Comment: That is a different question but the reason you're experiencing that is because you're hardcoding your textfield value. If you want to input your own values then remove your hardcoded value. Please check the updated answer. Also, please mark it as answer to help other with similar question.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a string as `string[1]`, you are asking for the second character in the string.

When you set `value`, you are setting it as a string. Try removing `.toString()` from the end of `value = getValue(kapController.text, buizenController.text, diamController.text).toString();` This way `value` will be a list and you can get the nth element of that list.

I'd also suggest setting the type of `value` when you first declare it. Instead of `var value;` use `List<double> value;`

Comment: Great, this is what I need. And it's expandable. Thanks a lot  P.s. Only one problem occurs this way. If you change the input it jumps back to the original value. When I change ie TextEditingController kapController = TextEditingController(text: '9.60') to TextEditingController kapController = TextEditingController() it stays empty. Before it stayed the new value. Something to figure out.

Comment: Yes thnx. I took the example below and figured out where I went wrong..